# In which situations NavigationService.CanGoBack returns false?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Before calling `NavigationService.GoBack()` we need to check if `NavigationService.CanGoBack` is true, but what are the situations that `NavigationService.CanGoBack` returns false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CanGoBack returns false if there is nothing in the navigation history.  There are times when the most recent entry (multiple navigators) may not have been added for the current navigator.

[link to documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.cangoback(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Jacob has mentioned, CanGoBack will be false if you're at the root of the navigation BackStack. It can also be false if you're replacing the root frame with a new one that also has no pages